# Move UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi everyone I am a newbie to iOS.

I have implemented a `UITableView` with 3 sections in  `UITableViewController`. And I have displayed the section rows to each section.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

sectionTittle=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Real Madrid",@"Barcelona",@"Liverpool", nil];
firstSection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cr7",@"Garath Bale",@"Pepe",
              nil];
secondSection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lionel Messi",@"Neymar",@"Pique",
              nil];
thirdSection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Gerrard",@"Saurez",@"Lallana",
               nil];


       }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sectionTittle.count;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


if(section==0)
{
  return [firstSection count];
}
if(section==1)
{
    return [secondSection count];
}
if(section==2)
{
    return [thirdSection count];
}
return 0;





  }


     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"hi" forIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor brownColor];



if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text=[firstSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}


if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [secondSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (indexPath.section == 2)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [thirdSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}




// Configure the cell...
     return cell;
    }

     - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

 return [sectionTittle objectAtIndex:section];
  }

  - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
  }
```

Now my output looks like this:

[image]

I want to move the rows between the these 3 sections. How can I do it..? While I try doing it the row moves between the section, but while saving it creates a problem.

How can i go through it..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilise UITableView re-ordering capacity. The cells can be re-ordered across sections.
To enable re-ordering mode:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:TRUE animated:TRUE];
```

This enables the TableView in editing mode which includes enables deletion mode along with re-ordering. If you do not want the deletion mode implement:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
```

}

The re-order support accessory view is shown if you have implemented moveRowAtIndexPath like, for your case:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

// Logic to change data source
NSMutableArray *deleteFrom = [self getDataSourceArrayFromIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
NSMutableArray *addTo = [self getDataSourceArrayFromIndexPath:destinationIndexPath];
[addTo insertObject:[deleteFrom objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
[deleteFrom removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

}
```

where getDataSourceArrayFromIndexPath is:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getDataSourceArrayFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) index
{
switch (index.section) {
    case 0:
        return self.firstSection;
        break;
    case 1:
        return self.secondSection;
        break;
    case 2:
        return self.thirdSection;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayTemp=[arrayMain objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arrayVisibleCountryList removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arrayVisibleCountryList insertObject:arrayTemp atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    //Uncomment these lines to enable moving a row just within it's current section
    if ([sourceIndexPath section] != [proposedDestinationIndexPath section])
    {
        proposedDestinationIndexPath = sourceIndexPath;
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: What does this code do? How does it work? And from where have you copied it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below tableView method. It moves your cell from **sourceIndexPath** to **destinationIndexPath**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
```